# google-cardboard, Quickstart for Google Cardboard for Unity, Build failed with error: resourse’style/theme.appcombat.noactionbar’ not found

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, google-cardboard

I’m a new developer and I'm trying for first time to building an android project according to this google forum to make VR projects for Androids: Quickstart for Google Cardboard for Unity  |  https://developers.google.com/cardboard/develop/unity/quickstart
But trying building this string occurred: resourse’style/theme.appcombat.noactionbar’ not found in androidmanifest.xml:87
I’m not sure to have done any mistake…of course I tried googling this, but no solution appeared to me. My only doubt is about chapter: Publishing Settings...IDK
I’m working on it from so much time and I really need the help of an expert, thanks for collaboration!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the instructions to include custom Gradle Properties and you should be good!